# PHP Change XML node values

Tags: php, xml

I'm having some difficulties in  changing XML Node values with PHP.

My XML is the following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
      xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
      <soap:Body>
            <ProcessTransaction
                  xmlns="http://example.com">
                  <TransactionRequest
                        xmlns="http://example.com">
                        <Header>
                              <RequestType>SALE</RequestType>
                              <RequestMethod>SYNCHRONOUS</RequestMethod>
                              <MerchantInfo>
                                    <PosName>kwstasna</PosName>
                                    <PosID>1234</PosID>
                              </MerchantInfo>
                        </Header>
                  </TransactionRequest>
            </ProcessTransaction>
      </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

And i want to change `PosName` and `PosID`.
The XML is received from a POST Request.
If i `print_r($REQUEST['xml']`
I get the values in text.

And what i've tried is the following

```
$posid = '321';
$posname = 'nakwsta';

$result = $xml->xpath("/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/ProcessTransaction/TransactionRequest/Header/MerchantInfo");

$result[0]->PosID = $posid;
$result[0]->PosName = $posname;

echo $result;
```

But i get an empty array `Array[]`

I think my mistake is in the values of `<soap:Envelope` for example.
Anyone that had the same issue and find out the way to solve it?

Thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: you have to register your namespace(s) to your $xml in order to get the right path (http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.registerxpathnamespace.php)

Comment: @Edwin at the first part that exist 3 namespaces what should i do?

Comment: you need to register your `xmlns="http://example.com"`, because this is the node that you are trying to use (see first example in the manual)

Comment: What is your desired result? A transformed XML or just parsed XPath values?

Comment: @Edwin its the same as the answer below right?

Comment: @Parfait my desired result is an XML with the updated values!

Comment: @KwnstantinosNatsios yes, but now I understand that you actually want not just to retrieve the values from the xml, but also to overwrite them. Yes?

Comment: @Edwin exactly ! and then have a new XML !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `ProcessTransaction` element (and all of its child nodes) are in the **"http://example.com"** namespace. If you want to access them using `xpath()`, you'll need to register a namespace prefix:

```
$xml->registerXPathNamespace('ex', 'http://example.com');
```

You can then use the `ex` prefix on all relevant parts of your query

```
$result = $xml->xpath("/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/ex:ProcessTransaction/ex:TransactionRequest/ex:Header/ex:MerchantInfo");
```

The rest of your code should function correctly, see https://eval.in/916856

Comment: great answer and your example is correct, but is there any way to transform it back to xml ?

Comment: You should just be able to call `$xml->asXML()`, I'll update with a new example

Comment: 100% correct. I didn't knew anything about namespaces. first time to grab an XML ! thank you so much !

Answer (score 2):

Consider a parameterized XSLT (not unlike parameterized SQL) where PHP passes value to the underlying script with [setParameter()](http://php.net/manual/en/xsltprocessor.setparameter.php).

As information, [XSLT](https://www.w3.org/Style/XSL/) (sibling to XPath) is a special-purpose language designed to transform XML files. PHP can run XSLT 1.0 scripts  with the [XSL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.xsl.php) class. Specifically, below runs the [Identity Transform](http://www.usingxml.com/Transforms/XslIdentity) to copy XML as is and then rewrites the *PosName* and *PosID* nodes. Default namespace is handled accordingly in top root tag aligned to *doc* prefix.

**XSLT** *(save as .xsl file, a special well-formed .xml file)*

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                              xmlns:doc="http://example.com">  
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

  <xsl:param name="PosNameParam"/>
  <xsl:param name="PosIDParam"/>

  <!-- IDENTITY TRANSFORM -->
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- RE-WRITE PosName NODE -->
  <xsl:template match="doc:PosName">    
    <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:value-of select="$PosNameParam"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- RE-WRITE PosID NODE -->
  <xsl:template match="doc:PosID">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:value-of select="$PosIDParam"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**PHP**

```
$posid = '321';
$posname = 'nakwsta';

// Load XML and XSL
$xml = new DOMDocument;
$xml->load('Input.xml');

$xsl = new DOMDocument;
$xsl->load('XSLTScript.xsl');

// Configure transformer
$proc = new XSLTProcessor;
$proc->importStyleSheet($xsl); 

// Assign values to XSLT parameters
$proc->setParameter('', 'PosNameParam', $posid);
$proc->setParameter('', 'PosIDParam', $posname);

// Transform XML source
$newXML = new DOMDocument;
$newXML = $proc->transformToXML($xml);

// Output to console
echo $newXML;

// Output to file
file_put_contents('Output.xml', $newXML);
```

**Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
      <soap:Body>
            <ProcessTransaction xmlns="http://example.com">
                  <TransactionRequest>
                        <Header>
                              <RequestType>SALE</RequestType>
                              <RequestMethod>SYNCHRONOUS</RequestMethod>
                              <MerchantInfo>
                                    <PosName>nakwsta</PosName>
                                    <PosID>321</PosID>
                              </MerchantInfo>
                        </Header>
                  </TransactionRequest>
            </ProcessTransaction>
      </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: this looks nice, but what's the advantage to do it like this? (thanks)

Comment: Right now it seems overkill since you are making small changes. But if you have to make substantial transformation like new nodes, flattening out children, convert to csv/txt, XSLT is a great tool as you avoid many `foreach` loops and `if` logic. Besides too I recently found out about passing parameters in PHP and Python, and just wanted to have fun with your question!