# How to parse xml with php to select child node?

Tags: php, xml

How can I select `InsCode` child node in this XML with PHP?

I use `simplexml_load_string` but I can't select a child node!

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<soap:Body>
<InstTradeResponse xmlns="http://tsetmc.com/">
<InstTradeResult>
<xs:schema xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" id="TradeSelectedDate">...</xs:schema>
<diffgr:diffgram xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1">
<TradeSelectedDate xmlns="">
<TradeSelectedDate diffgr:id="TradeSelectedDate1" msdata:rowOrder="0">
<InsCode>70270965300262393</InsCode>
<DEven>20160507</DEven>
<HEven>123452</HEven>
<PClosing>1303.00</PClosing>
<IClose>0</IClose>
<YClose>3</YClose>
<PDrCotVal>1297.00</PDrCotVal>
<ZTotTran>222</ZTotTran>
<QTotTran5J>1966165</QTotTran5J>
<QTotCap>2561539385.00</QTotCap>
<PriceChange>-35.00</PriceChange>
<PriceMin>1270.00</PriceMin>
<PriceMax>1355.00</PriceMax>
<PriceYesterday>1332.00</PriceYesterday>
</TradeSelectedDate>
<TradeSelectedDate diffgr:id="TradeSelectedDate2" msdata:rowOrder="1">
<InsCode>70270965300262393</InsCode>
<DEven>20160508</DEven>
<HEven>122959</HEven>
<PClosing>1287.00</PClosing>
<IClose>0</IClose>
<YClose>3</YClose>
<PDrCotVal>1309.00</PDrCotVal>
<ZTotTran>281</ZTotTran>
<QTotTran5J>2600251</QTotTran5J>
<QTotCap>3347398897.00</QTotCap>
<PriceChange>6.00</PriceChange>
<PriceMin>1244.00</PriceMin>
<PriceMax>1310.00</PriceMax>
<PriceYesterday>1303.00</PriceYesterday>
</TradeSelectedDate>
</TradeSelectedDate>
</diffgr:diffgram>
</InstTradeResult>
</InstTradeResponse>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I try this code:

```
print_r ($data->InstTradeResult);
$xml  = $data->InstTradeResult->any;
//print_r($xml);
$sxml = simplexml_load_string( $xml );
$json = json_decode( json_encode( $sxml->xpath) );
```

Comment: What's the result of the code you tried ?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47755945/php-change-xml-node-values

Comment: result is : "stdClass Object ( [schema] => [any] => )"

Comment: `<InsCode>70270965300262393</InsCode>` - InsCode has no child

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is only one `<InsCode>` element, then you can just use XPath.  As this returns an array of matches, you just take the first element (using `[0]`) and convert the value to a string...

```
$sxml = simplexml_load_string( $xml );
$body = $sxml->xpath("//InsCode");
echo (string)$body[0];
```

Which with the sample XML you have gives...

```
70270965300262393
```